# Pusher with nodejs not work under proxy network

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, pusher

I follow guide from [Pusher JS is not working from node JS in some network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707546/pusher-js-is-not-working-from-node-js-in-some-network/26708766#26708766) to set proxy in my code. However, it shows error in my terminal.

[image: error]

The following is my code to add proxy server.

```
  var Pusher = require("pusher");
  var pusher = new Pusher({
     appId: config.app_id,
     key: config.key,
     secret: config.secret,
     proxy: 'http://username:password@proxynework:ppr\#',
     timeout: TIMEOUT, 
     keepAlive: KEEP_ALIVE
    });
```

Comment: Please post actual error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `TIMEOUT` hasn't been set anywhere (you'll have the same issue with `KEEP_ALIVE` too).  You've got a couple of options to resolve this:

1) set the timeout and keepAlive

```
//...
proxy: 'http://username:password@proxynework:ppr\#',
timeout: 2000,
keepAlive: false
```

2) leave them out (they're optional)

```
  // ...
  proxy: 'http://username:password@proxynework:ppr\#'
  // use default timeout and keepalive values
});
```